# Get exception in Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to create an AspNetCore Middleware (old IHttpModule), which should capture exceptions (later on save them or something similar)

However, i don't know how to capture the Exception inside Middleware, although the HttpStatusCode is 500

Here is what i have:

```
// Middleware
internal class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // never gets here
        }

        // 500
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = (HttpStatusCode)context.Response.StatusCode;

        // how to get error message?
    }
}

// Middleware Extension method
public static class ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseExceptionMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
    }
}

// Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseExceptionMiddleware();

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I trigger the exception like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var test = 0;
    var a = 100 / test;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I think my question is a bit different. I do not want to alter existing configuration, but to make it as unobtrusive as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You correctly use `try-catch` in middleware.

But your problem is that you also register the [ExceptionHandler middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) (`app.UseExceptionHandler`). This middleware catches all unhandled exceptions and set 500 status code if could handle it.

---

As a possible solution consider to swap the order of middlewares, so your middleware will be the first one that catches the exceptions occurred further in the pipeline:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseExceptionMiddleware();
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this. If i do that, the default Exception Handler gets overwritten. 
For example,

`app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`
`app.UseExceptionMiddleware();`

Developer exception page doesn't work anymore. If i remove my line of code, it gets back.

But indeed, i now capture the exception in `try { } catch { }`

Comment: @Catalin yes, cause [DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs)  expects exceptions, and your middleware swallow them. It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve, but If you need just to log exceptions in your middlewares and then want to use ExceptionPages  then you need to rethrow exceptions in your middleware

Comment: Bingo! i'll give it a try, and come back

Answer (score 7):

You're re-inventing the wheel.

**How to do it right without your own middleware:**

You can get error details using built-in [`ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3a868d87a2458fd025ca71e2538b3a72f67c7c50/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerExtensions.cs#L19-L27) (`app.UseExceptionHandler`) ASP.NET Core gives you, this is not documented but it should be.

[When exception occurs this middleware sets `IExceptionHandlerFeature` (with exception that occured) and `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature` (with derives from `IExceptionHandlerFeature`)  on `HttpContext`.](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/d22bb2c908f5aed83aefe4ca8a94227251ba820c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L65-L71)

So you can access your exception details through `HttpContext.Features`:

Assuming you're invoking this inside your `/Home/Error` controller's action you can access it like:

```
var exHandlerFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
var exception = exHandlerFeature.Error;
```

[Also see this answer and question about Request Features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34994561/2828480)

[There's a blog post about this too if you are interested](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/centralized-exception-handling-and-request-validation-in-asp-net-core/)